# почему текст не записывается в файл?

Tags: java, filewriter

```
FileWriter output;

if (inputName == null) output = new FileWriter(outputName);
else {
   Path in = Paths.get(inputName);
   String o = in.getParent() + File.separator + outputName;
   output = new FileWriter(o);
}
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(output);
for (String str : resultList){
   writer.write(str);
   writer.newLine();
}
output.close();
```

Comment: `writer.Close();` потеряли?

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что причина заключается в том, что вы используете `BufferedWriter`, который работает по принципу буфера, следовательно запись происходит только тогда, когда буфер заполнится, но в вашем случае, видимо, он не заполняется полностью, поэтому запись не происходит. Чтобы решить эту проблему, вам нужно вручную вызвать метод `flush()` у вашего Writer'a. В этом случае данные из буфера принудительно будут записаны

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `try-with-resources`:

```
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(output)) {
        for (String str : resultList) {
            writer.write(str);
            writer.newLine();
        }
    }
```